# Troubles with API Calendar while trying to insert a new Event

Tags: javascript, events, google-api, calendar

I'm working with the Calendar API of Google. At this point I'm trying to insert a new event using JavaScript, but a I get the next error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'events' of undefined
at evento (scriptLogIn.js:73)
at handleAuthResult (scriptLogIn.js:28)
at h.o0 (cb=gapi.loaded_0:85)
at xs (cb=gapi.loaded_0:88)
at Wq (cb=gapi.loaded_0:88)
at _.C.uea (cb=gapi.loaded_0:88)
at Ap (cb=gapi.loaded_0:81)
```

This is the Java Script code that I'm using to call de API:

```
function evento(){
  var event = {
   'summary': 'Google I/O 2015',
   'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
   'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
   'start': {
    'dateTime': '2018-06-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
   },
   'end': {
    'dateTime': '2018-06-29T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
   },
   'recurrence': [
     'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
   ],
   'attendees': [
    {'email': 'lpage@example.com'},
    {'email': 'sbrin@example.com'}
   ],
   'reminders': {
     'useDefault': false,
     'overrides': [
      {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
      {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10}
     ]
   }
 };

 var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.insert({
   'calendarId': 'primary',
   'resource': event
 });

 request.execute(function(event) {
  alert("evento creado");
 });
}
```

I call the function evento() when the user's process authentication is correct, and that's when I get the error that I showed you before.

Note: I followed the instructions of the google reference in the next link: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

I also added the reference to the API script in my HTML file.

I wish you can help me.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think that the reason of error might be the scopes. Could you please confirm whether ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`` is included in the scopes? In my environment, when the scope is not included in the scopes for the authorization, the same error occurred.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time. Yes, I have included that scope in my code, in fact, I use that scope to begin the user authentication, and I don't modify it at any part of my code.